# react-query useMutation when useQuery with parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Would someone advice me what is correct approach to update a data with useMutation when useQuery has parameters?

Lets assume we have this code:

```
const {data} = useQuery(["key", ["id1", "id2"]], methodWhichTakesThoseIds)
```

So the method `methodWhichTakesThoseIds` takes `["id1", "id2"]` and returns some data from database. This data is an array of objects type like `SomeModel[]`. For eg. it could be:

`[{name: "foo"}, {name:"bar"}]`

All good, but now I want to update this data on screen and on database with `useMutation`

```
const [mutate] = useMutation(methodWhichUpdatesDataAndReturnsNewItem, {
        onSuccess: (data) => {
            queryCache.setQueryData(["key", ["id1", "id2"]], (old) => [...old, data]
            })
        }
    })
```

So now I added new item to database and the data in case should be: `[{name: "foo"}, {name:"bar"}, {name:"newOne"]`.

All good again, but when I change the route and back again, the useQuery with only 2 IDs will fire again and useQuery returns data with only two element from database because it has only two IDs as paramters `["id1", "id2"]`.

If I'll set `queryCache.setQueryData(["key", ["id1", "id2", data.id]], (old) => [...old, data]` I'm still using original useQuery with only two IDs so changes won't reflect on screen.

I guess there are solutions like refetch data from server every time after update, but main question is"

What is the best approach to update data when useQuery has parameters - not only the key like `useQuery("key", method)` ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you don't need to cache all the fetch queries that take diff sets of IDs

so instead of this:

```
const { data } = useQuery(["key", ["id1", "id2"]], methodWhichTakesThoseIds)
```

do:

```
const fetchWrapper = (params) => () => methodWhichTakesThoseIds(params);
const { data } = useQuery(["key", 'fetchData'], fetchWrapper(["id1", "id2"]));
```

then after your mutation, you can simply call your `onSuccess` like this to update cache:

```
onSuccess: (data) => {
  queryCache.setQueryData(["key", "fetchData"], (old) => [...old, data];
}
```